# Just keep reading

Tags: rhyme, story

> There was a philosopher, living in a castle
>   He knew many secrets, that was his downfall
>   Taken prisoner, for secrecy's sake
>   Promised to fire, to be burnt at the stake
>   But an order came, to free him right away
>   Coming from the prince, at the end of the day
>   Now that he escaped from that deathly fate,
>   Can you tell me to what these lines relate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This relates to the

> Harry Potter Series of books by JK Rowling.

There was a philosopher, living in a castle

> Book 1: Harry Potter and the *Philosopher’s* Stone (it was Sorceror’s in the US, but I’m Canadian ;p )

He knew many secrets, that was his downfall

> Book 2: Harry Potter and the Chamber of *Secrets*

Taken prisoner, for secrecy's sake

> Book 3: Harry Potter and the *Prisoner* of Azkaban

Promised to fire, to be burnt at the stake

> Book 4: Harry Potter and the Goblet of *Fire*

But an order came, to free him right away

> Book 5: Harry Potter and the *Order* of the Phoenix

Coming from the prince, at the end of the day

> Book 6: Harry Potter and the Half-Blood *Prince*

Now that he escaped from that deathly fate,

> Book 7: Harry Potter and the *Deathly* Hallows

Can you tell me to what these lines relate?

> Each line contains one of the words in the title of a HP novel, in chronological order.

Comment: I knew it was easy, but that was quick nonetheless :)